# Use formula inside script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to use a formula inside a custom function, like this for example:

```
function myFunction(range, value) {
    var countNumber = COUNTIF(range; value); // COUNTIF is a formula that can be used in the spreadsheet
    if (countNumber > 0) {
        return "RESULT";
    } else {
        return "OTHER RESULT";
    }
}
```

And then:

`=MYFUNCTION(A1:A5,"VALUETOTEST")`

---

I would like to simplify a huge formula:

Something like:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(G182:G186;"ERROR";H182:H186;"62");COUNTIFS(G182:G186;"ERROR";H182:H186;"ALL"))>0;"ERRO";IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(G182:G186;"RETEST";H182:H186;"62");COUNTIFS(G182:G186;"RETEST";H182:H186;"TODOS"))>0;"RETEST";IF(COUNTIF(G182:G186;"UNIMPLEMENTED")>0;"UNIMPLEMENTED";"SOLVED")))
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it has solved your issue or provided a furthering insight. This helps others find your question and the resulting solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem. I thank to people who helped me to reach this result!

```
// Like COUNTIFS
var countConditionals = function(cells, condition1, condition2) {

  var count = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {

    if (cells[i][0] == condition1 && cells[i][1] == condition2) {
      count++;
    }

  }

  return count;
}

// Like COUNTIF
var countConditional = function(cells, condition) {

    var count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {

        if (cells[i][0] == condition) {
          count++;
        }

    }

  return count;
}

//Whole Formula
function verificaStatus(cells, db) {

  const ERROR  = "ERROR";
  const ALL    = "ALL";
  const RETEST = "RETEST";
  const NOTYET = "UNIMPLEMENTADED";
  const SOLVED = "SOLVED";

  var countErrors    = countConditionals(cells, ERROR, db);
  var countErrorsAll = countConditionals(cells, ERROR, ALL);
  var sumErrors      = countErrors + countErrorsAll;

  if (sumErrors > 0) {
    return ERROR;
  } else {

    var retest    = countConditionals(cells, RETEST, db);
    var retestAll = countConditionals(cells, RETEST, db);
    var sumRetest = retest + retestAll;

    if (sumRetest > 0) {
      return RETEST;
    } else {

      var countNonCreated = countConditional(cells, NOTYET);

      if (countNonCreated > 0) {
        return NOTYET;
      }

    }

  } 

  return SOLVED;

}
```

Answer (score 8):

You have three ways of performing these actions.

1. Add the Sheet Formulas to the sheet itself in the ranges that you need. Then read the data from the result cells (wherever you set it to write to) using your GAS Function. You can then perform further processing using the results.
2. Use your GAS function to write Sheet Formulas into your sheet. Then use more GAS to read that result and process the data. The method for this can be found here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula(String)
3. You can create a Custom Sheet Formula using GAS that you then use in your sheet. GAS can then read that result and process the information. This will require some research into JS as a whole to know how to recreate, combine, and perform the operations that you need the data in the sheet to perform.

You can find a guide to make Custom Formulas here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

And a guide to JS here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

W3 Schools has a quite comprehensive guide to JS. GAS uses all native JS methods as it is a JS coding environment. Check the GAS Reference for more on GAS-specific methods that may perform what you need.

If what you need is to check conditions and/or iterate through rows, try something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns);
var values = range.getValues(); //This is a 2D array; iterate appropriately
  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] == conditionToCheck) {
      //perform code..OR
      //continue; <- This works to skip the row if the condition is met
    } else {
      //perform alternate code if condition is not met
    }
  }
}
```

As I mentioned, `.getValues()` creates a 2D array. If you need to iterate through columns and rows, you will need 2 `for()` loops like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { //iterates through the rows
  for(j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) { //iterates through the columns in that current row
```

It is important to mention how GAS handles 2D arrays. `values[i][j]` denotes how much `i` rows there are and `j` columns. You can visualize like so:

`values = [[A1, B1, C1],[A2, B2, C2],[A3, B3, C3]]`

This is an array of arrays where the outer array is an array of the rows, while the insides are an array of cell values by column in that row.

Comment: For example. I will have to count cells based on a condition. But for this, I will have to read a range of cells. I would need a foreach in cells. There is `sheet.getRange()`, but how do it chage to the next cell? How would I know it is in the end of the range?

Comment: What you're looking for is a `for() {` loop along with an `if() {} else {` statement. `for() {` loops allow iteration through a range; the `if()` statement checks for a condition at each iteration. I will edit my answer to reflect an example. If this example suffices, please accept the answer as solving the issue.

Comment: Way #1 in this answer is the way to call a Google Sheets function from a Google Apps Script function. Put the GS function into a cell, referring to another cell for each of its input parameters. Eg. for a GAS function to call a GS function to add two values: put =SUM(A1:B1) into cell C1. Then in the GAS function put var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(firstVal); sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(secondVal); var sumVal = sheet.getRange("C1").getValue(); You can use named ranges instead of literal cell addresses.

Comment: Way #2 in this answer is the way for a GAS function to insert a standard GS function into the sheet, so all the code is in the GAS script rather than manually configuring the sheet.

Comment: Way #3 in this answer is the way to create a new GS function in the GAS script, without relying on a standard GS function. It's really a way for the GS sheet to use the same code as the GAS script, so the function can be used in either the GS sheet or the GAS script.

Answer (score 1):

Custom functions in google apps script do not have access to spreadsheet function. You may try using this `=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A5,"VALUETOTEST")>0,"RESULT","OTHER RESULT")`

If there is a huge formula for result, try creating functions for the result

```
function result1() {
     return "RESULT";
}

function result2() {
     return "OTHER RESULT";
}
```

Then use this `=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A5,"VALUETOTEST")>0,RESULT1(),RESULT2())`

Try this - copy the below function in apps script, and use this as Formula `=myFunction("G182:G186","H182:H186")` remeber to ensclose the range with ' `"` '  because you will be passing the range as string, and note both the ranges must be of equal length.

```
function myFunction(aRange, bRange) {

    var cond_1 = "ERROR";
    var cond_2 = "62";
    var cond_3 = "ALL";
    var cond_4 = "RETEST";
    var cond_5 = "TODOS";
    var cond_6 = "UNIMPLEMENTED";


    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var aRange = sheet.getRange(aRange);
    var aValues = aRange.getValues();
    var bRange = sheet.getRange(bRange);
    var bValues = bRange.getValues();
    var count = 0;
    var tmplength = 0;

    if (aValues.length != bValues.length) {
        return "Range length does not Match";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < aValues.length; i++) {

        if (aValues[i] == cond_1 && bValues[i] == cond_2) {
            count += 1;
        }
        if (aValues[i] == cond_1 && bValues[i] == cond_3) {
            count += 1;
        }

        if (count > 0) {
            return "ERROR";
        } else {
            count = 0;

            if (aValues[i] == cond_4 && bValues[i] == cond_2) {
                count += 1;
            }
            if (aValues[i] == cond_4 && bValues[i] == cond_5) {
                count += 1;
            }

            if (count > 0) {
                return "RETEST";
            } else {
                count = 0;

                if (aValues[i] == cond_6) {
                    count += 1;
                }
                if (count > 0) {
                    return "UNIMPLEMENTED";
                } else {
                    return "SOLVED";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, but it is because I have a huge formula.

Comment: There would be another way to do this?

Comment: You'd have to recreate the formula as a function within GAS

Comment: Yes, that's I would like to do, to create a function. What you mean GAS?

Comment: This is what I want. But I would replace a COUNTIFs formula with my function that do the same.

Comment: It is kind of this, but I think my solution was a little bit simpler. I'll show you.